# XCode 4 unable to attach to iPhone Simulator - double application

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode4

when I run my application in iPhone simulator it works fine the first time. But the second time the application is duplicated (two same icons) and XCode tries endlessly to attach the debugger. The problem began when I renamed my project.

What is the problem and what could be done?

[image: Screenshot for error]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that helps.

```
Product -> Manage Schemes
```

You could try to `Autocreate schemes` or just look for the old project and deselect it.

Answer (score 2):

For xcode 4.1: Create a new template app from xcode 4.1, then build and run it. 
This resets the simulator-xcode bridge correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Open the "active scheme" dropdown menu (near the stop button)
Select the simulator (example: iPhone 4.3 Simulator)
now open "active scheme" dropdown again and select "edit scheme"
select "Run Appname.app" in the left column
enable Launch Automatically option

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a couple of days ago and i was going crazy.

The issue was caused by a change i performed on the /etc/hosts file. I forgot to delete the extension (.txt, that was hidden) before replacing the old file with the new one (so the hosts file could not be used).

I found this solution after realizing that i was unable to solve "localhost" (i had problems with every other apps which need to solve hosts names, like MAMP).

Comment: Crazy. I would have never guessed. +1